# How to sorts "tags" numeric and add increment with one using Bash script

Tags: bash, ubuntu, gitlab

How to create a bash script that finds the previous `a_tag*` tag and increases the value by one, and pipe this script into the git tag command so that the tag is tagged with the next tag? 
Because of all the tags are unsorted.

1. If I search for the tags in Ubuntu, they show up unstructured like this:

   ```
   $ git tag -l a_tag*
   ```
2. Sorting the numbers for the tags:

   ```
   $ git tag -l m_itp* | cut -d'-' -f 2 | sort -n -r
   ```

How to pipe my code for implementing increment the tags and get the tags sorted when I search for it?

Output for 1:

```
a_tag-0
a_tag-1
a_tag-10
a_tag-11
a_tag-12
a_tag-13
a_tag-14
a_tag-15
a_tag-16
a_tag-17
a_tag-18
a_tag-19
a_tag-2
a_tag-20
a_tag-21
a_tag-22
a_tag-23
a_tag-24
a_tag-25
a_tag-26
a_tag-27
a_tag-28
a_tag-29
a_tag-3
a_tag-30
a_tag-4
a_tag-5
a_tag-6
a_tag-7
a_tag-8
a_tag-9
```

---

Output 2:

```
30
29
28
27
26
25
24
23
22
21
20
19
18
17
16
15
14
13
12
11
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

---

3 The results I want and implement in bash script:

Expected results:

```
a_tag-31 (new tag and sorted)
a_tag-30
a_tag-29
a_tag-28
a_tag-27
a_tag-26
a_tag-25
a_tag-24
a_tag-23
a_tag-22
a_tag-21
a_tag-20
a_tag-19
a_tag-18
a_tag-17
a_tag-16
a_tag-15
a_tag-14
a_tag-13
a_tag-12
a_tag-11
a_tag-10
a_tag-9
a_tag-8
a_tag-7
a_tag-6
a_tag-5
a_tag-4
a_tag-3
a_tag-2
a_tag-1
a_tag-0
```

Comment: Your progress seems ok and at the end I would give try to the bash calculator command, e.g. echo "3+1" | bc and it will print 4 so you can increase the value by 1.

Comment: When I write echo "3+1" | bc, it won't show up anything.
I would expect it shows "a_tag-31".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort it in reverse order like that:

```
$git tag |sort -Vr
```

and for last tag:

```
$git tag |sort -Vr|head -1
```